# Algorithms for a line follower robot (with camera) capable following very sharp turns and junction

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, robotics, opencv3.1

I want to write code (python,opencv) for a line follower robot equipped with a camera and Raspberry Pi. I want to make to robot go has fast as possible

1. The course has few very sharp turns like this: [image: https://imgur.com/a/h07WlAD/] I'm assuming that using ROI (region of interest) will not work well when the robot in near the turn (it will also capture/"see" the other line) - for example as shown below. What is the best approach here?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/b9K66Rp]

2. In the course there is a junction as shown in below image,
   [image]

   How to "understand" that this is a junction? and if the robot is
   coming for the bottom of the image, how to make the algorithm
   continue driving straight and not get confused by the horizontal
   line?

Comment: I have a question, what did you do until now?

Comment: I'm experimenting, I wrote a code that slices the input image from the camera (horizontal). On each slice I run threshold-> findcontours-> find the centeroid of the contour. I keep track on the line using a sliding window, because on the right to of the line (in some places) there are signaling lines and I need to filter them out. When I get close to a sharp  turn, the sliding doesn't work well

Comment: By sharing that code we can help you better, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this awesome video on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpwokAPiqfs&t=868s

It contains several episodes and teachs a lot of useful stuff. Good luck!!!